# SQL Query to split date and time from a column

Tags: sql, datetime

what will be the query to split date and time from 'etime' column? table name is 'emp'

| ID | ENAME | EDATE | ETIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kunal | 15-03-23 |  |
| 2 | Rohit | 15-03-23 | 31-01-97 9:26:50.124000000 AM |
| 3 | Sakshi | 15-03-23 | 31-01-97 9:26:50.124000000 AM |

```
ID          NUMBER       
ENAME       VARCHAR2(20) 
EDATE       DATE         
ETIME       TIMESTAMP(6)
```

i tried this query but it didn't work.

```
SELECT DATE(etime) AS date, TIME(etime) AS time
FROM emp;
```

Comment: Why did it not work?  What results did you get?

Comment: and what database technology is this for?

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your Date Time Column once try below query

```
SELECT  CAST(etime AS date)[DATE],CAST(etime AS TIME) [TIME]
```

If you want to format you format like below query

```
SELECT  FORMAT(CAST(etime AS date),'dd/MM/yyyy')[DATE],FORMAT(CAST(etime AS DATETIME),'hh:mm:ss') [TIME]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this sample code. I'm not sure if the datatype Timestamp(6) exists that you use in your question. I can't find it at [datatypes at ms-learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) so I used the datetime2 datatype to show the parsing:

> ```
> declare @dateTimeToConvert as datetime2(6)  = getdate();
> select cast(@dateTimeToConvert as date) myDate,  cast(@dateTimeToConvert as time) myTime;
> ```

Answer (score -1):

For MS SQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST (etime AS VARCHAR),1,8) AS date,
       SUBSTRING(CAST (etime AS VARCHAR),10,100) AS time
  FROM emp
```